# Error when trying to export more than one module.exports

Tags: node.js

I am trying to upload an image to memory using multer, then process it with sharp and save it to disk. When I try to do multiple module.exports in my middleware.

The error is:

> TypeError fileUpload.single is not a function

```
const multer = require("multer");
const sharp = require("sharp");


const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
  "image/png": "png",
  "image/jpg": "jpg",
  "image/jpeg": "jpeg",
};

const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage();

const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
  let error = isValid ? null : new Error("Invalid mime type");
  cb(error, isValid);
};

const fileUpload = multer({
  storage: multerStorage,
  fileFilter: multerFilter,
});

const resizeUserPhoto = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.file) return next();

  req.file.filename = `hero-${Date.now()}`;
  sharp(req.file.buffer)
    .resize(400, 400, {
      fit: sharp.fit.outside,
    })
    .toFormat("jpeg")
    .jpeg({ quality: 80 })
    .toFile(`uploads/images/${req.file.filename}`);

  next();
};

module.exports = { fileUpload: fileUpload, resizeUserPhoto: resizeUserPhoto };
```

The route so far is:

```
const express = require("express");
const userController = require("../controllers/userController");
const fileUpload = require("../middleware/file-upload");

router.post(
  "/update-avatar",
  fileUpload.single("image"),
  userController.updateAvatar
);
```

When I just had the below in the route before trying to add image processing I didn't get an error;

```
module.exports = fileUpload;
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is with your route file. If `module.exports = {fileUpload, resizeUserPhoto}` you want to require it like this: `const { fileUpload } = require('../middleware/file-upload');`

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a second pair or eyes to prove we're not crazy.

Comment: Haha, yeah, true! If you want to add that as the answer then I can close the question. Or I can delete it if you would prefer?

Comment: I'll add the answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're importing the whole `module.exports` instead of only selecting the export you need.

Update the routes file to destructure the `fileUpload` export:

```
const express = require("express");
const userController = require("../controllers/userController");
const { fileUpload } = require("../middleware/file-upload"); // only grab the export you are using

router.post(
  "/update-avatar",
  fileUpload.single("image"),
  userController.updateAvatar
);
```